# Add Dynamically Value in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular2-directives

I want to add display value(in `<mat-option>`) dynamically using `ngFor`. In my HTML code i have added `{{'selected'+ displayValue}}` under `<mat-option>` and `displayValue` is defined in Class. Can somebody help on this.
Thanks.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel" (ngModelChange)="changedValue($event)"
    name="food" [compareWith]="compFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let selected of SelectedObjectData" [value]="selected">
      {{'selected' + displayValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
export class SelectboxComponent {

  displayValue = 'viewValue'

  SelectedObjectData: any[] = [{ value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
  { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
  { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }];

  @Input() selectedValueModel = { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' };

  @Output() selectedValueModelChange = new EventEmitter()

  changedValue(newValue: any) {
    this.selectedValueModel = newValue
    this.selectedValueModelChange.emit(newValue)
  }

  compFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.value === c2.value : c1 === c2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ideally {{selected.viewValue}} shows properly in HTML. But in {{selected.viewValue}} i want to pass dynamic thing to viewValue from my SelectboxComponent Code. So i have added {{'selected'+ displayValue}} in my HTML  and 'displayValue' is defined in SelectboxComponent Code. I Hope question is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your html mat-option

```
{{selected[displayValue]}}
```

Check Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-my8wzh?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have gotten your bindings wrong. Your `displayValue` will always display the string 'viewvalue' on your view. In order to show the display the selected food and the other options, you need to make use of the access the binded `selected` object, and select the `viewValue` string property to be displayed on view.

I have made the relevant edited below.

component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"
   [(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel"
   (ngModelChange)="changedValue($event)" name="food" [compareWith]="compFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let selected of SelectedObjectData" [value]="selected">
        {{'selected'+ selected.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts:

```
export class SelectboxComponent {

  displayValue= 'viewValue'

    SelectedObjectData: any[] = [{ value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }];

  @Input() selectedValueModel = {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'};

  @Output() selectedValueModelChange = new EventEmitter()

  changedValue(newValue: any) {
    //this.selectedValueModel = newValue
    //this.selectedValueModelChange.emit(newValue)

    // selected value will be reflected here, do what you want with the newValue object
    console.log(newValue)
  }

  compFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.value === c2.value : c1 === c2;
  }
}
```